# "Forbidden" error uploading to Google Drive via API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I've been playing around with the [.NET Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/dotnet), and I can successfully connect, authenticate and get a list of files via the API (we already have several thousand files on our Google Drive account, uploaded directly via the web).

However, I'm getting two very similar errors when trying to write data: if I try to upload a test file (`test.txt`), I get a 403 "Forbidden" error. Trying to create a new folder gives me a similar error:

> Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in Google.Apis.dll
>
> Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>
> Insufficient Permission [403] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]

I've followed the "Quick Start" tutorial, and other similar questions here, but I can't see what else I have to do. Here's my sample code for uploading a file; what do I need to add/change in my code, or in the Google Drive account itself, to allow uploading of files and creation of folders?

```
 class GDriveTest
{
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive,DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        UploadSingleFile(service);
    }

    private static void UploadSingleFile(DriveService service)
    {
        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "My document";
        body.Description = "A test document";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        File file = request.ResponseBody;
        Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code for UploadSingleFile

Comment: @DaImTo: the code's already there?

Comment: oops sorry scroll bar :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the scope you are requesting

```
DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,   // view and manage files created by this app
```

try

```
DriveService.Scope.Drive,  // view and manage your files and documents
```

My Code:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Authenticate to Google Using Oauth2
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">The user to authorize.</param>
        /// <returns>a valid DriveService</returns>
        public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
                throw new Exception("clientId is required.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecret))
                throw new Exception("clientSecret is required.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new Exception("userName is required for datastore.");


            string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive};

            try
            {

                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/Drive");

                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                throw ex;
            }

        }

/// <summary>
        /// Insert a new file.
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive//v2/files/insert
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="service">Valid authentcated DriveService</param>
        /// <param name="body">Valid File Body</param>
        /// <returns>File </returns>
        public static File Insert(DriveService service, File body)
        {
            //Note Genrate Argument Exception (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(loband).aspx)
            try
            {  
            return          service.Files.Insert(body).Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request Failed " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
         }

  private static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
        {
            string mimeType = "application/unknown";
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
            if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
                mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
            return mimeType;
        }
```

Execution

```
var driveService = StandardGoogleAuth.AuthenticateOauth("xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", "uxpj6hx1H2N5BFqdnaNhIbie", "user");

                var uploadfileName = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
               File body = new File();
                body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadfileName);
                body.Description = "File uploaded by Diamto Drive Sample";
                body.MimeType =  GetMimeType(uploadfileName);
                body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = "root" } };

                // File's content.
                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadfileName);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

             var result = FilesSample.Insert(driveService,body);
```

Comment: Afraid not - even after changing my `string[] Scopes` to just `DriveService.Scope.Drive` (rather than both `.Drive` and `.DriveFiles`), I still get a 403 :(

Comment: did you change "user" to force it to request the new scope?

Comment: I just tested it with the code I normally use.  It worked from me I am not seeing much difference between this and the code you use.

Comment: Did you have to do anything on the Google Drive side of things to explicitly grant permissions for your application?

Comment: nope its using Oauth2 grants permissions to a Users Drive account.   As long as your project is set up on Google developer console and is set to access drive it should work with out touching the users drive account.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the scope will not be updated automatically into the TOKENRESPONSE User file. You have to regenerate that file.

Search for the "drive-dotnet-quickstart.json" and delete the "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user" from inside it.
Then run your code to regenerate that file.